# Module build failed when using babel

Tags: node.js, vue.js, babeljs

I'm working on Laravel and VueJS application. Just want to use babel. Setup necessary babel packages:

npm install @babel/core --save-dev
npm install @babel/preset-env --save-dev
npm install babel-core --save-dev
npm install babel-jest --save-dev
npm install babel-loader --save-dev to ^7.0.0-0.

but when I run npm run watch it show following error:

ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                            5:13:44 PM

error  in ./resources/assets/js/app.js

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
Error: [BABEL] /home/vagrant/code/mypos/resources/assets/js/app.js: 
As of v7.0.0-beta.55, we've removed Babel's Stage presets.

My development environment: Ubuntu, node version v11.5.0,

Comment: Please show us the contents of your babel config file and the code of your  `./resources/assets/js/app.js`. It is usually a lot faster if you provide the full code or at least a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: in side .babelrc content is: 
{
  "presets": [ "@babel/preset-env",
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-stage-2"
  ],
"plugins": [
"transform-es2015-arrow-functions",
"check-es2015-constants",
"transform-es2015-block-scoping"
]
}

Comment: Please edit your post and add the config in a code-block with proper formatting. :P - but the error is caused by preset-stage2. Remove it from presets and you are fine.

Comment: AND app.js content is:

require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
import VueResource from 'vue-resource';
Vue.use(VueResource);
Vue.component('warehouse-store-in-challan-create', 

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});